# Scenario in multi-threaded socket communication

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have socket client application,  during application startup the socket is created(connection established with server) and it starts two threads which run in parallel.

Thread-1: continuously reads the socket using read method (blocks until data is received)

Thread-2: continuously writes the data.

While writing the socket, if thread-2 receives IO exception, then it discards the existing socket and creates new socket and starts communication. Since thread-2 discards the socket, the thread-1 receives null pointer exception.
Do we have any strategy to handle this

Comment: This is not 'asynchronous', this is multi-threaded. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Thread 2 needs to shutdown the socket for input before closing it. That will cause thread to receive and end of stream, which should cause it to close the socket and exit. Then thread 2 can create another socket and start another read thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are beginning to encounter the problems associated with the `proactor` style of system design. Solving this problem requires some communication between the two threads. Choosing what this communication is is where it gets messy. It has to be something that stops thread1 from trying to read the socket. I'm not so good with Java, but in C, this means using a signal.

I suggest you avoid signals, even if there is an equivalent in Java.

One better option is to have thread1 blocked on a call to `select()` (or whatever the Java equivalent is), waiting on the socket and on a pipe. Thread2 writes to the pipe when it wants to close the socket, thread1 returns from select(), writes a response to thread2 down the pipe, and calls select() again but only on the pipe. Thread2 reads that response, closes the socket, opens a new one, sends something else down the pipe to wake up thread1 again, which can now go back to `select()` but this time on the pipe and the new socket. This achieves an execution rendezvous between thread1 and thread2; thread2 can close the old socket and open a new one because it knows (via the pipe communication) when thread1 is not using the socket.

This is somewhat messy. And also becoming more like the `reactor` design pattern. In which case one may as well simply have just one thread that uses `select()` to choose whether to read the socket as part of whatever loop it is executing. This single thread would be reading data when it is available, not doing a blocking read in the hope that data arrives. If something goes wrong with a socket write and the socket needs to be replaced, it simply does so; there's no other thread to sync with. Assuming your socket is connected to a remote server on a network (rather than a service on the same machine), the speed of the Ethernet will still be the dominant bottleneck; reactor style systems are no slower.

In general, dealing with network failures is far easier with the `reactor` systems style, because you don't have threads committed to carrying out actions that other threads know to be inappropriate. Unfortunately, most programming environments are `proactor`, eg Windows, Boost ASIO, RabbitMQ, etc. Proactor systems are fine until something goes wrong, after which it is often necessary to throw the whole process away because it can easily become insanely complicated for the programmer to sort out all the borked callbacks and async IOs.

One option is to use ZeroMQ if you can. This requires you to be using ZeroMQ everywhere (server too), but it makes it far easier to deal with network problems. It is a reactor, not a proactor.